# Possibility to skew haproxy?

Tags: haproxy

haproxy is a load balance proxy. However my use case is to make haproxy to direct traffic to server A, and ONLY if server A is down, and haproxy should direct traffic to server B which basically does nothing except displaying a page of "under construction" or "temporarily unavailable" for every coming requests.

Comment: That's called "hot standby" and/or "failover", there should be plenty of docs on how to set this up - though it's a question more appropriate for serverfault.com

Answer (score 3):

Designate Server B as "backup":

```
backend backend_servers
    server R1 192.168.1.100:80 maxconn 1000 check
    server R2 192.168.1.101:80 maxconn 1000 backup check
```

R2 will only get requests if R1 is down.

Comment: Of course you would need to enable checks to be able to automatically mark servers as down. Then the `backup` option is in fact the solution. See the [the docs](http://cbonte.github.com/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.4.html#5-backup) for more information.